# Changed Mac homefolder name, Docker doesn't start

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I have renamed my home folder name (let's say from userA to userB) and Docker stopped working.

The error is:

*Cannot create/resize "/Users/**userA**/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.dockser.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2":exit status 1"*

Notice that the path it shows is to the old folder name, userA. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Docker CE from the docker store (https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac) but still have the same error.

Why is it still using the old folder even after I uninstalled?

Comment: Changing the unix user name or home path always causes problems like this in my experience, it’s best to start with a new user account

Comment: for that, I would prefer to revert the name to the old one

Answer (score 4):

You need a clean setup.

**WARNING**: the below procedure will delete all of your containers and images❗️

Try to **delete** following folders: some of them may require `sudo` privileges.

```
~/.docker
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
~/Library/Caches/com.docker.docker
~/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.docker.vmnetd
~/Library/Preferences/com.docker.docker.plist
```

Comment: This worked for me, but be aware that it will DELETE all your containers and images.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and would prefer not to rez it, but this answer came up when searching Google and I found a better solution that doesn't require you do delete anything - which I felt would be useful for anyone who comes across this question.

Assuming the old name is UserA, and the new is UserB

1. Create a new UserA directory in `/Users/`, then all the directories in the "missing" file path. IE: `Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.dockser.driver.amd64-linux/`
2. Move Docker.qcow2 from `UserB/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.dockser.driver.amd64-linux/` to the directory created in step 1.
3. Start Docker
4. Open Docker preferences -> Go to the Disk menu
5. Select "Move Disk Image" and pick the new location to move that docker file into. IE: you'll want to move it to `UserB/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.dockser.driver.amd64-linux/`

[image]